# CSS opacity broken on unordered list items in IE7 and IE8

Tags: css, html, html-lists, opacity, styling

I am having an issue with the CSS opacity attribute with IE7 and IE8. On IE9/FF/Chrome/Safari/Opera the code work below, in that the opacity attirbute works correctly.

I have read that the element that the opacity is being applied to must have "a layout", however I have tried that, and although I get some success on IE8 (it kills other CSS attributes) it does *not* work on IE7.

Is there a simple, low-risk solution for IE7 and IE8?

```
<div id="link_contents">
    <ul>
        <li><a>Poulter</a></li>
        <li><a>Lawrie</a></li>
        <li><a>Hanson</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


    #link_contents ul {
        width: 200px;
        height: 110px;
        padding-top: 40px;
    }

    #link_contents ul a {
        font-size: 14pt;
        color: #000;            
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        padding: 3px;
        opacity: 0.75;
        filter: alpha(opacity=75);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try adding `-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75)";` rule as well? What doctype is used?

Comment: Isnt `zoom: 1;` need aswell on opacity layers for IE?

Comment: @raina77ow Adding the `-ms-filter` attribute certainly seems to add the correct affect to the appropriate elements, however it seems to knock the _positioning_ out for some reason. I cannot understand how adding a filter that applies an opacity value would affect the positioning. This occurs on IE8.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're going to be fresh out of luck for IE7, but check this link out:
http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/

IE7&8 have real sketchy CSS compatibility, luckily almost no one uses these versions of IE anymore. I think this link should help you. You may also need conditional CSS for IE, which is common for almost any site now. google "Conditional CSS IE" for more info on that.

HOpe it helps, good luck!